# Elementary OS 0.3 Freya can't be installed

Tags: system-installation

[image: MY LAPTOP HP COMPAQ NX6320][![HALF WAY PAUSED INSTALLATION ]..During installation Elementary OS Freya, I clicked on Install Elementary ,Then when "Preparing to Elementary screen comes simply clicked on 2 options  DOWNLOAD UPDATES WHILE AND INSTALLING AND INSTALL 3rd-PARTY SOFTWARE and clicked continue .After that the black wheel just rotating and rotating,,2 hours gone nothing comes.....
[image]
PLEASE I NEED HELP
BY THE WAY
MY LAPTOP - HP COMPAQ NX6320 (PRETTY OLD MODEL) 8 YEARS APPROX.
RAM - 1 GB
HDD- 80 GB
NO GRAPHICS CARD
I SUCCESSFULLY INSTALLED OS LIKE WINDOWS ALL VERSIONS INCLUDING WINDOWS 10,UBUNTU 16.04 LTS,LINUX MINT,ON THIS ABOVE SAID LAPTOP.

Answer (score 1):

Since it is an old laptop, I would recommend checking if the hard drive is still operational. You should be able to do this from the live CD / USB by installing Disks from the app center and then running a SMART test on the hard drive. If you have numerous relocated sectors and / or categories marked as fail in the Assessment column your hard drive is bad.

Answer (score 0):

Try running it without connecting to the internet and without installing updates or third-party software. Then just install that stuff and connect to wifi after you boot from hardware.